# 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponseAsync' in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await

I am trying to make a asynchronous http request in a core (for iOS and Android) project in Xamarin.

Reading up on the new Async, I felt like this was the best way to do it. The core project is used through File Linking rather than Project Core Library.

However I get a error both in Android and iOS:

```
'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponseAsync'
```

I have tried System.Net.WebRequest as well. My code:

```
private async Task<String> fetchXML ()
{
    String url = "http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/V%C3%A4stra%20G%C3%B6taland/G%C3%B6teborg/forecast.xml";
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create (url);
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.Method = "GET";

    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync ();
    //...
```

Any ideas? The error is the same compiling for both Android and iOS. Using latest Xamarin Studio for Mac.

Comment: It was probably just overlooked. Xamarin platforms do support `HttpClient`; is there a reason you chose `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: Thanks! `HttpClient` worked better!

Comment: Its the portable class framework that doesn't support the method, not Xamarin themselves